# terminate called without an active exception thread c++

Tags: c++, terminate

Good evening, I've found this error for many hours and I found many solutions but they don't work.

C_t is a vector of vector and it's size is 100. If the loop is until 8 it works but when I increased it, the error is thrown.

f is a vector that save evalutions of C_t.

func is the kind of function.

```
int nThreads = thread::hardware_concurrency();  // # threads
vector<thread> ths(nThreads);   // threads vector
cout << ths.size() << endl;

//Launching threads
int idx = 0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ){

    ths[idx] = thread( parallel_eval, ref(f[i]) ,  ref(C_t[i]) , func);

    // idx = idx != nThreads ? idx++:0;
    if(idx != nThreads){
        idx++;
    }
    else{
        idx = 0;
    }
    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}

//Joining threads
for ( int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++ ){
    ths[i].join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Error is most likely caused by `ths`. Explanation:

You save hardware concurrency level:

```
int nThreads = thread::hardware_concurrency();
```

You create container for thread objects:

```
vector<thread> ths(nThreads);
```

Then, you create and save up to `N` threads:

```
ths[idx] = thread( parallel_eval, ref(f[i]) ,  ref(C_t[i]) , func);
```

And here is your problem:

```
if(idx != nThreads)
{
    idx++;
}
else
{
    idx = 0;
}
```

This condition essentially means: *"Save thread under current index. If we reached `nThreads`, set index to `0` and continue saving there*.

So, basically, if you set limit of `N` (control value of your loop and number of threads being created) to value greater than `nThreads`, you **overwrite your thread objects** (via move assignment operator). Why is that a problem? Because [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D) says:

> **std::thread::operator=**
>
> Assigns the state of other to `*this` using move semantics.
>
> If `*this` still has an associated running thread (i.e. `joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called.

Since threads objects you overwrite represent **active** threads, condition for calling `std::terminate()` is met.

Also, we can now easily tell why every `n <= 8` works: most likely your **`hardware_concurrency()`** is **8**.

I would go for:

```
vector<thread> ths; //No need for any size restrictions. `vector<>` is a dynamic container, it will grow as necessary.

for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
{
    ths.emplace_back(parallel_eval, ref(f[i]) ,  ref(C_t[i]) , func);
}

for (auto t = ths.begin(); t != ths.end(); ++t)
{
    t->join();
}
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine. Salute!

Comment: Wrong member function - you want the move assignment operator, not the destructor. The "terminate if joinable" part is the same, though.

Comment: Thank you, Mateuz. It works but i don't get a speed up or acceleration. I will check it. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

Willing to put money on nThreads == 8.

If his is the case, `vector<thread> ths(nThreads);` will be created with 8 elements in it's internal array and `ths[idx] = thread( parallel_eval, ref(f[i]) ,  ref(C_t[i]) , func);` will go boom on the 9th thread.

Solution: Either lock the initial size of ths to the number of threads you are going to create, or don't bother allocating the initial size of ths and `push_back` or `emplace_back` the threads.